# How to get Express route's body parameters as 'string' instead of 'any' in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, http, parameters

I'm sending a `string` `productId` using a hidden input type through a `<form>`:

```
<form action="/cart" method="POST">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<%= product.id %> ">   // EJS template engine
</form>
```

And then receiving the `productId` in an Express route as follows:

```
export const postCart = async (request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> => {
    const productId = request.body.productId   // This is inferred as type 'any'
    const allProducts = //...Array<Product>
    const requestedProduct = allProducts.find((product) => product.id === productId)  // Problem: this is always false
}
```

### Problem

The condition `product.id === productId` is always `false` because the type of `product.id` from the database is `string` and type of `productId` received from the `body` is `any`. I need a way for both of them to be of same type.

### What I tried so far

I tried annotating and casting the type of productId:

```
const productId: string = request.body.productId              // Doesn't work
const productId: string = request.body.productId as string    // Doesn't work
const productId: string = request.body.productId + ''         // Doesn't work
```

The only thing that works is, if I create the `Number`s from the `id`s:

```
Number(product.id) === Number(productId)
```

But this can't be a solution because I'm using UUID strings for representing the product `id`. And casting UUIDs to the numbers may not be a good idea.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a typescript (compile time) issue? or a runtime issue?

Comment: @AndreiTătar, it compiles fine. But at runtime it doesn't find the product due to the types not being equal.

Comment: Do you have the body parser middleware added to express (http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)? I suspect `request.body` is a string so `request.body.productId` will be `undefined`.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only reasonable explanation here is that `product.id !== productId`. Comparing a string type to an any type isn't a factor here. Why not introduce some logging to find out exactly what you're dealing with here? It's worth remembering that data received from clients can be any shape... not just the shape you expect. There are good arguments for keeping the type as `any` until you actually validate that you have what you think you have.

Comment: @AndreiTătar, yes I'm using the built in body parser: `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`. `request.body.productId` should not be undefined, because casting it to a `Number` works.

Comment: @spender If I `console.log()` `product.id` and `productId` they are same, yet the condition for some reason is being false. Probably because `===`also considers types. They are not equal in this case.

Comment: I strongly suspect `product.id` and `productId` are not the same. You are operating on an assumption that is just wrong. Try `console.log(typeof product.id)` and `console.log(typeof productId)`. It sounds to me that productId is a string already and you are trying to convert a string to a string which generates no errors of course. But product.id is a number and you are trying to compare a string to a number.

Comment: @slebetman, `product.id` is `string` because I have `id: string` in my `Product` class. Let me check `console.log(typeof product.id)`.

Comment: `I have id: string` -- remember that javascript has no types so all type information from Typescript is removed from the compiled code. Types save you ONLY from things in the source code. If data comes from elsewhere eg. a database, some API call etc. then you cannot trust that they comply with typescript's types because there is no more type information by the time the data is processed.

Comment: @slebetman, ah, yes, thanks for reminder. So, I checked the `console.log(typeof product.id)` and `console.log(typeof productId)` they are both `string`, so apparently it may not be a problem related to types. But how do you explain the fact that the condition becomes `true` only when I convert them to `Number`. How do I make it work by keeping them as strings only?

Comment: @YogeshUmeshVaity Can you paste the strings here?

Comment: @AndreiTătar, which strings? The `productId`s? They are UUID strings like: `3bbcee75-cecc-5b56-8031-b6641c1ed1f1`

Comment: Yes, maybe they have a small space, or upper/lower case mismatch, weird unicode chars, etc. Best would be to add a breakpoint and inspect the members.

Comment: maybe even this space here at the end: `<input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<%= product.id %> ">`

Comment: @AndreiTătar, Oh, man! The space was the problem! Removing the space solved it. You can post your answer, so I can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we chatted out in the comment section but the problem seems to have been the trailing space in the html:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<%= product.id %> ">
```

updated to:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<%= product.id %>">
```